# Apache Hudi throwing Dataset not found exception when storing to S3

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-hudi

I am trying to load a simple dataframe as Hudi dataset into S3 and I am having trouble in doing that. I am new to Apache Hudi and I am trying to load the data from by running the code locally on my Windows machine. All the Maven dependencies I am using to achieve this and the code along with exceptions are mentioned below

```
inputDF.write.format("com.uber.hoodie")
.option(HoodieWriteConfig.TABLE_NAME, tablename)
.option(DataSourceWriteOptions.RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "GameId")
.option(DataSourceWriteOptions.PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY,"operatorShortName")
.option(DataSourceWriteOptions.PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "HandledTimestamp")
.option(DataSourceWriteOptions.OPERATION_OPT_KEY, DataSourceWriteOptions.UPSERT_OPERATION_OPT_VAL)
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.save("s3a://s3_buket/Games2" )

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.11.623</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.uber.hoodie</groupId>
<artifactId>hoodie</artifactId>
<version>0.4.7</version>
<type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.uber.hoodie/hoodie-spark -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.uber.hoodie</groupId>
<artifactId>hoodie-spark</artifactId>
<version>0.4.7</version>
</dependency>

Exception in thread "main" com.uber.hoodie.exception.DatasetNotFoundException: Hoodie dataset not found in path s3a://gat-datalake-raw-dev/Games2\.hoodie
at com.uber.hoodie.exception.DatasetNotFoundException.checkValidDataset(DatasetNotFoundException.java:45)
at com.uber.hoodie.common.table.HoodieTableMetaClient.<init>(HoodieTableMetaClient.java:91)
at com.uber.hoodie.HoodieWriteClient.rollbackInflightCommits(HoodieWriteClient.java:1172)
at com.uber.hoodie.HoodieWriteClient.startCommitWithTime(HoodieWriteClient.java:1044)
at com.uber.hoodie.HoodieWriteClient.startCommit(HoodieWriteClient.java:1037)
at com.uber.hoodie.HoodieSparkSqlWriter$.write(HoodieSparkSqlWriter.scala:144)
at com.uber.hoodie.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
at com.playngoplatform.scala.dao.DataAccessS3.writeDataToRefinedS3(DataAccessS3.scala:26)
at com.playngoplatform.scala.controller.GameAndProviderDataTransform.processData(GameAndProviderDataTransform.scala:29)
at com.playngoplatform.scala.action.GameAndProviderData$.main(GameAndProviderData.scala:10)
at com.playngoplatform.scala.action.GameAndProviderData.main(GameAndProviderData.scala)
```

I am not doing anything else apart from this. I am just creating a Hudi dataset directly from my Spark data source code. I am seeing the folder getting created the S3 path but not any further
.hoodie.properties file is mentioned below

```
hoodie.compaction.payload.class=com.uber.hoodie.common.model.HoodieAvroPayload
hoodie.table.name=hoodie.games
hoodie.archivelog.folder=archived
hoodie.table.type=MERGE_ON_READ
```

Answer (score 0):

Hudi is not completely mature to support your windows OS.

The issue is fixed by changing file seperation character in terms of running this on windows machine.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might want to add further clarification on how to do what you propose in your answer.